# How creating a new database schema for an Oracle 18c XE installation

Tags: oracle

I've an Oracle 18c XE installation on my machine.
I've tried to create a new schema, but unsuccessfully.
I've used these statements:

- CREATE SCHEMA test
- CREATE SCHEMA test AUTHORIZATION test

but I've always the same error:
Report error -
02420. 00000 -  "missing schema authorization clause"
*Cause:    the AUTHORIZATION clause is missing from a create schema
statement.
*Action:   Preceed the schema authorization identifier with the
AUTHORIZATION keyword

I've also tried to specify: CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION test
but I've this error:
Report error -
02421. 00000 -  "missing or invalid schema authorization identifier"
*Cause:    the schema name is missing or is incorrect in an authorization
clause of a create schema statement.
*Action:   If the name is present, it must be the same as the current
schema.

I cannot to create a new user.

Now, can I create a schema and/or an user in Oracle 18c XE installation?
Thanks

Comment: The `create schema` statement [creates objects under your existing schema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-SCHEMA.html#GUID-2D154F9C-9E2B-4A09-B658-2EA5B99AC838); which is synonymous with a user in Oracle. If you want to create a *new* schema then you need to create a user. But you said "I cannot to create a new user" - why not?

Comment: Do you say that I need to create a new user as a first thing?
I've tried to do it with this statement: CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY test
but I've this error:
Report error -
65096. 00000 -  "invalid common user or role name"

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to the pluggable database (PDB) and not the container database (CDB). Application users/schemas/objects do not belong in the CDB, which also has special naming rules. If you are connected to the PDB then your `create user` command should work fine.

Comment: I've installed the Oracle 18c XE. I'm a beginner with this database technology. With SQL Developer I can see more tables. How can I distinguish between a CDB and a PDB?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/pdb/pdb_basics/pdb_basics.html

Comment: I'm talking about an Oracle Express Edition, it is a limited edition of Oracle.

Comment: @Pasquale - [the 18c XE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/connecting-oracle-database-xe.html) shows how to connect the default XEPDB1 PDB - essentially connecting to its service instead of the CDB's.

Comment: After the connection to the XEPDB1 PDB I've created a new user, but I cannot to connect using it:
-- USER SQL
ALTER USER "MyTestUser"
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
PASSWORD EXPIRE 
ACCOUNT UNLOCK ;
-- QUOTAS
ALTER USER "MyTestUser" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "USERS";
-- ROLES
ALTER USER "MyTestUser" DEFAULT ROLE "CONNECT","RESOURCE";
I've an error about username/password not valid; I've controlled them more times.

Comment: @Pasquale - when you try to connect as that new user, is *that* connection to the PDB? If it's to the CDB then the user won't be recognised, so that's probably what you're doing. Use the PDB service name in the new connection.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Hi, inside SQL Developer for the connection with the new user I've specified "XEPDB1" as a service name, how I've already done for that connection useful to create the new user.

Answer (score 1):

To create a user that can then do the "usual" stuff like create tables and the like, you use the CREATE USER command and assign some privs.  The following should suffice:

```
create user DEMO 
identified by MySuperCoolPassword;

grant RESOURCE, CONNECT to DEMO;
alter user DEMO quota unlimited on USERS;
```

If you only want to do this with the GUI in SQL Developer, here's a complete video walkthrough

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDJacg0NuLo